# mysqli query doesn't insert row in database

Tags: php, mysqli

Hope you guys can help me, I've been trying to figure out what seems to be my error but to no avail, here is my code:

```
**This is my index.php**

<?php
include('config.php');
if($_POST['submit']=='Borrow')
{   
    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `borrowersprofile`(`lastname`, `firstname`, `middlename`) VALUES(
                            '".$_POST['lastname']."',
                            '".$_POST['firstname']."',
                            '".$_POST['middlename']."',
                            NOW())");

    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<label for="lastname">Lastname:</label>
<input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" style="width:120px;"/>

<label for="firstname">Firstname:</label>
<input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" style="width:120px;"/>

<label for="middlename">M.I:</label>
<input name="middlename" type="text" id="middlename" style="width:35px;"/><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Borrow" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the config.php

```
<?php 
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_name = 'bsystem';
$db_host = 'localhost';
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name);
?>
```

I've been trying to check and even tried to remake the database but its still not adding data, btw, this is a school project so security doesn't really matter, hope you guys can help me out! Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the return status of the insert query in the database?

Comment: You are giving five varail in value while four in colun name

Comment: Security always matters.

Comment: You have to check by printing your query and then run this query in `phpmyadmin`
then you will know what is error with query.

Comment: Would be helpful to list any errors you're getting on screen or in your log, and the database format. Where is NOW() expected to go? Looks like you don't have a field for that.

Comment: @MarkTe, look at Ankit's answer below

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @user328

1) Assuming the `ID` or `primary key` of your table is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, therefore you do not need to mention `ID` column in your query. Sql inserts it automatically for you.

2) You need to mention the column name where to save the value returned by `now()`.

```
if($_POST['submit']=='Borrow')
{   
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `borrowersprofile`(`lastname`, `firstname`, `middlename`, `DATE`) VALUES(
                        '".$_POST['lastname']."',
                        '".$_POST['firstname']."',
                        '".$_POST['middlename']."',
                        NOW())");

header("Location: index.php");
exit;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to create this table in your database and then use the script below.

sql table:

```
CREATE TABLE `borrowersprofile` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`lastname` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`firstname` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`middlename` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`datetime` DATETIME NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once('./config.php');

if(!empty($_POST['lastname']) AND !empty($_POST['firstname']) AND !empty($_POST['middlename'])){

   $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
   $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
   $middlename = $_POST['middlename'];

   if ($stmtint = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `borrowersprofile`( `lastname`, `firstname`, `middlename`, `datetime`) VALUES(?, ?, ?, NOW())") {

       $stmtint->bind_param("sss", $lastname, $firstname, $middlename);

       if ($stmtint->execute()) {
           $stmtint->close();
           echo "User saved successfully!";           
       }else{
           die("Error Message:".$mysqli->error);
       }

       header("Location: index.php");
       exit;
    }  
}
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<label for="lastname">Lastname:</label>
<input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" style="width:120px;"/>

<label for="firstname">Firstname:</label>
<input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" style="width:120px;"/>

<label for="middlename">M.I:</label>
<input name="middlename" type="text" id="middlename" style="width:35px;"/><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="borrow" />

</form>
</body>
```

config.php

```
<?php
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_name = 'bsystem';
$db_host = 'localhost';
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
?>
```